# Show sum in a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have problem in excel:

Let's say in `C2` its value is `1+1`

and then in `C3` I want to show the sum of `C2` so the value of `C3` will be `2`.

I can do this in WPS using `=EVALUATE(C2)`, but I can't do this in excel.

Comment: If you only have a `+` as delimiter it is quite possible to sum these, however if you want to evaluate any calculation it will become increasingly difficult if not impossible without VBA.

Comment: What is your actual goal? Show more sample data. Excel function doesn't support evaluating expression. You will need then VBA.

Comment: @Harun24hr its more of a sum computation the actual goal is  C3 will calculate the value of sum inside of C2 1+1

Comment: FYI. https://superuser.com/a/774135

Comment: @martyg FILTERXML would be best for this case. `=SUM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"+","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use VBA this might prove being very simple, as you can see from this screenshot:

[image]

The function `evaluate_Formula()` is defined in VBA as follows:

```
Public Function evaluate_Formula(target As Range)
  evaluate_Formula = Evaluate(target.Value)
End Function
```

As far as the way I have defined this, I'll add another screenshot for clarity reasons:

[image]

As you see, I've added a module, and I've added the mentioned VBA code into that module.
Don't worry about "Solver.xlam", this is not relevant to this matter.

Comment: When I add this in Vba I cant see it on macro is that normal? but when I put insert the code inside of Sub Eval() to it it shows but an error comes up with

Comment: @martyg: I've added another screenshot, showing where I've added the VBA code with regards to the rest of the Excel file.

Comment: Oh: don't forget to put the keyword `Public` in front of your function, or Excel won't recognise your function.